# Terraform: How to loop through list of elements and create resources based on each element?

Tags: amazon-s3, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I need to setup aws s3 access points for each `data_uri` passed in the `inference` variable; this is to provide a cross-account uri(s). I need to parse out just the bucket name from each of these `data_uri` and then create resources for each. How would I go about doing that?

Here is what I have so far:

```
resource "aws_s3_access_point" "s3_access_point" {
  count    = var.create ? 1 : 0
  for_each = var.inference

  bucket = split("/", replace(each.value.image_uri, "s3://", ""))[0]
  name   = format("%s-%s", split("/", replace(each.value.image_uri, "s3://", ""))[0], "-access-point")
}
```

The variable would look like this:

```
{
"inference": [
  {
  "data_uri": "s3://my_bucket/model.tar.gz"
  },
  {
  "data_uri": "s3://my_bucket_2/model.tar.gz"
  },
  {
  "data_uri": "s3://my_bucket_3/model.tar.gz"
  }
]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend using [split](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/split) if the naming is this consistent. Also, you cannot mix [count](https://www.terraform.io/language/meta-arguments/count) and [for_each](https://www.terraform.io/language/meta-arguments/for_each); use one or the other as the case requires.

*note*: This answer has been reworked based on the comments below

```
locals {
  inference = [
    { "data_uri" : "s3://my_bucket/model.tar.gz" },
    { "data_uri" : "s3://my_bucket_2/model.tar.gz" },
    { "data_uri" : "s3://my_bucket_3/model.tar.gz" }
  ]

  uri_bucket_map = {
    for x in local.inference : x.data_uri =>
    split("/", split("//", x.data_uri)[1])[0]
  }
}

resource "aws_s3_access_point" "s3_access_point" {
  for_each = local.uri_bucket_map

  bucket = each.value
  name   = var.s3_access_point_name
}

output "s3_access_point" {
  value = { for uri, ap in aws_s3_access_point.s3_access_point : uri => ap.arn }
}
```

In this iteration, we generate a map from `data_uri` to `bucket_name` so that you can access both when needed. You could of course still just use the `toset` version of the uri's and calculate the bucket within the resources, but since you preferred this method so you can access the bucket names elsewhere, I went with the map.

After the resources are created, we then generate an output that is a map from `data_uri` to access point arn.

Comment: Since we can't combine `for_each` and `count`, how do I not create the resources when the create flag is set to false ?

Comment: You can add a condition on for expressions, like: `for_each = toset([for x in local.inference : x.data_uri if var.create])`.

Comment: Where do I add the conditional if I use the first method. Your first method might work better because I can reuse the bucket name value for the s3 access point name and don't have to split text multiple times.

Comment: Well, then it would be something like: `for_each = toset(var.create ? local.bucket_names : [])`.

Comment: Would you happen to know how to create a mapped output that references the s3 uris?

Comment: ```output "s3_access_point_arn" {
  description = "The arn of the access point"
  value = {
    for access_point, details in aws_s3_access_point.s3_access_point :
    access_point => ({ "bucket" : details.name, "arn" : details.arn })
  }
}
``` But I need the key to be the s3 uri that maps to the access point arn

Comment: I'm not really sure what you seek, but I added some output options to the answer.

Comment: For output I need a map: key = the original s3 uri before it was parsed out and value is the s3_access_point arn.

Comment: Okay, well that means you need an object with both `data_uri` and `bucket_name`, so I simplified the answer entirely. Let me know if that help.

Comment: I think so, thanks, and then can I still do something like this? `var.create ? local.uri_bucket_map: []`?

Comment: Yes. Well, I think you'd want something like `for_each = var.create ? local.uri_bucket_map : {}` to match types, but still yes.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for [Terraform's `regex` function](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/regex) includes an example containing a pattern for matching the scheme and authority parts of URLs, which is a simplification of the pattern given in [RFC 3986 Appendix B](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#appendix-B):

> ```
> > regex("^(?:(?P<scheme>[^:/?#]+):)?(?://(?P<authority>[^/?#]*))?", "https://terraform.io/docs/")
> {
>   "authority" = "terraform.io"
>   "scheme" = "https"
> }
> ```

These S3 URLs seem to follow the usual URL productions and so one way to parse these would be to run them through that same regex pattern:

```
> regex("^(?:(?P<scheme>[^:/?#]+):)?(?://(?P<authority>[^/?#]*))?", "s3://my_bucket/model.tar.gz")
{
  "authority" = "my_bucket"
  "scheme" = "s3"
}
```

To do this I'd first derive a new value from `local.inference` which expands out those URLs:

```
locals {
  data_uris = [
    for o in local.inference : merge(
      {uri = o.data_uri},
      regex("^(?:(?P<scheme>[^:/?#]+):)?(?://(?P<authority>[^/?#]*))?", o.data_uri),
    )
  ]
}
```

The `merge` in the above is to combine the regex results with the original input URIs to get a single simple object for each of the inputs:

```
[
  {
    uri       = "s3://my_bucket/model.tar.gz",
    scheme    = "s3"
    authority = "my_bucket"
  },
  {
    uri       = "s3://my_bucket_2/model.tar.gz",
    scheme    = "s3"
    authority = "my_bucket_2"
  },
  {
    uri       = "s3://my_bucket_3/model.tar.gz",
    scheme    = "s3"
    authority = "my_bucket_3"
  },
]
```

We can then do a little more filtering/projection inside `for_each` to transform this into a set of bucket names, to filter them all out if `var.create` isn't set, and to skip any that aren't S3 URLs:

```
resource "aws_s3_access_point" "s3_access_point" {
  for_each = toset([
    for ap in local.data_uris : ap.authority
    if var.enabled && ap.scheme == "s3"
  ])

  bucket = each.key
  name   = "${each.key}-access-point"
}
```

The use of regex here is admittedly not ideal because it's pretty unclear what that regex pattern is doing. If you move forward with this then I would suggest including source code comments noting that this regex is parsing the URI and possibly linking to RFC 3986 Appendix B for its explanation of the pattern.